# Drawing a one-dimensional byte array as an image

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have a one-dimensional array which is a 64x64 image 8 bits.  I want to display this on a Windows Form, but I dont know how to do this.  Can someone provide a sample code to perform this.

```
byte [] image = new byte[64*64];
```

I have tried this:

```
   ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
   Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(image); <--- Parameter not valid error
   Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(img);
   bitmap1.SetResolution(64, 64);

   e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 400, 10);
```

But this doesn't work, and I get a `Parameter not valid error`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, display an image in a windows form application, but what i don't understand is what you try to accomplish by doing it this way, what do you want to achieve? Are you trying to create a drawing application?

Comment: do you mean you have **byte data** of your image? of course it will be a *1 dimensional array*.

Comment: Please show how `image` is being populated in order to clarify what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, so the image is being captured by a camera at a small resolution and I am grabbing a 64 by 64 roi, so I can show it on the windows Form.  Is this not the way to do this?

Comment: The main problem is probably that the converter does not know how to interpret/understand the byte array. Even raw bytes have a formatting/meaning: rgb, rgba, argb, ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert your byte array into an image:

```
byte [] imageBuffer = new byte[64*64];

... populating the byte array...

Image image = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

In order to show it on your form, you need to add to your form a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control, amd set it's `Image` property:

```
pictureBox1.Image = image ;
```

Comment: No it is not loaded from file, I am grabbing the data from a camera and it is providing me a byte array.  I am choosing a ROI of 64x64 and I want to display this in the windows form.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, I tried it but I still get an error Parameter not valid in the image=Image.FromStream(ms) call.

Comment: @Godspped I have tested this code and it works if `imageBuffer` is a valid image AND it is not null. This is also specified in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110.aspx). You can test if yourself if you replace the declaration of `ms` with the following: `Stream ms = new FileStream(@"Path to some local image from hard drive", FileMode.Open)`